# Ao usar history.push() meu componente não renderiza, é necessário dar um reload na página para renderizar

Tags: react, react-router-dom

Estou utilizando react-router-dom para trabalhar com as rotas em uma aplicação React.

Possuo um arquivo chamado AppRouter.js que possui minhas rotas:

```
const AppRouter = props => {

    const loading = useSelector(state => state.loadingStates)
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: "/login",
                            }}
                        />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/registrar" component={LoginWrapper} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginWrapper} />
                </div>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default AppRouter
```

Meu arquivo index.js renderiza esse arquivo de rotas:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
            <AppRouter/>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Então, quando eu vou para a url localhost:3333 eu sou redirecionado para a tela de login. Quando eu estou na tela de login e realizo login, eu chamo um history.push('/home'):

```
function* makeLogin(action) {
    yield put(allActions.loadingActions.startLoading());
    try {    
        const { data } = yield call(api.post, '/login', action.payload);
        yield put(allActions.loginActions.setUser(data))
        yield put(allActions.loadingActions.endLoading());
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data))
        history.push('/home')
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

A url no meu browser é atualizado para localhost:3333/home porém a tela de login ainda é mostrada, é necessário realizar um reload da página para que o componente renderize.

Esse é meu arquivo history.js que é importado pelo arquivo saga.js que realiza a requisição de login:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

Comment: Não tenho certeza como funciona o `react-router-dom`, mas não deveria ser `window.location.href = '/home'` ?

Comment: é um problema complicado de reproduzir. @MarceloBoni não não ...

Comment: consegui resolver adicionando o history no meu appRouter, logo posto como consegui resolver

Comment: Mesmo problema comigo, fiz downgrade como dito na resposta abaixo, funcionou comigo.

Comment: Mesmo problema comigo, fiz downgrade como dito na resposta abaixo, funcionou comigo. –

Comment: Realmente é a versão. Aconteceu algo semelhante comigo, estava utilizando a versão 5.0 do history e ao fazer um downgrade foi só recarregar a pagina que funcionou. Após muita pesquisa e tentativas consegui resolver. Obrigado por postarem a solução aí!! Valeu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu estava sofrendo com o mesmo erro e no meu caso o problema está ocorrendo por conta da versão do `history`, então fiz o downgrade da versão do `history` e resolveu o problema.

```
yarn remove history
yarn add history@^4.10.1
```

Comment: Mesma coisa aconteceu comigo aqui, fui pesquisar pra ver se era só comigo, agora preciso entender o porquê a versão 5 está com esse problema.